Searchable Dropdown using Thymleaf and SpringBoot
enter image description here My DropDown getting like this
enter image description here my table
<select class="form-control custom-select" id="status" name="name" form="ordersForm"
    th:object="${allusers}">
<option selected>Select user</option>
<option th:each="users : ${allusers}" 
    th:text="${users}"  
        th:value="${users}">User</option>
</select>

